# How do we get more twitter followers?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, twitter

Our twitter following is anemic, how can we increase it and thereby increase our visibility? 
Also, I think it is confusing that we have 2 twitter accounts
[Mi_Yodeya](https://twitter.com/#!/mi_yodeya) (currently with 126 followers) and
[StackJudaism](https://twitter.com/#!/StackJudaism) (16).

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/956/what-is-the-difference-between-twitter-accounts

Comment: @IsaacMoses definitely related but for anyone on the outside, still very confusing.

Comment: I meant that that's a related question. I agree that it doesn't make sense, long-term, for both of these accounts to exist for essentially the same purpose. I've offered to give control of mi_yodeya to SEI (along with the relevant domains that I control), and they're reportedly thinking about what the best course of action is.

Comment: In any case, I'm not convinced that the site's twitter account will ever be a major generator of interest from the outside. As Jeff Atwood points out in [this relevant answer on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100964/179), "Part of the reason Twitter is interesting is because the accounts are actual people, not generic services or companies." Based on that standard, a robotic, auto-populated, site account is doomed to be relatively uninteresting in that medium, while individual Yodeyans tweeting on their own accounts about favorite content from time to time would be much more effective.

Comment: @IsaacMoses l'hefech. I would scrap the auto-generated account in favor of a mod powered human one. that would be able to engage the twitter community and would probably lead to more followers.

Comment: I agree that that would be potentially more effective. And it doesn't necessarily have to be *mod*-powered, in particular. A small group of trusted users could be designated. Perhaps we could implement something like this on an unofficial basis using @mi_yodeya. I could turn off the auto-feed and instead give access to a few users to post with it.

Comment: @IsaacMoses great, but I think this question still stands. I would love for people to share some strategies on how to increase our twitter followers. I will share some of mine.

Comment: @IsaacMoses bump

Comment: @AdamMosheh You rang?